# Strict standards: Declaration of B::foo() should be compatible with that of A::foo()

Tags: php

I'm using php5.3.10, and I have some problem code like this:

```
<?php
class A {
    function foo($bar = 0) {}
}

class B extends A {
    function foo($bar) {}
}
```

there are no php errors showed.

But, if I split the code in two files, like this:

**1.php**

```
<?php
class A {
    function foo($bar = 0) {}
}
```

and

**2.php**

```
<?php
require '1.php';
class B extends A {
    function foo($bar) {}
}
```

it give me a message "Strict standards: Declaration of B::foo() should be compatible with that of A::foo()".

so, how does this happen, why does it show the message after I split it in two files ?

Answer (score 0):

Your class B should look something like this:

```
class B extends A {
    function foo ($bar = 0) {} 
}
```

5.3 appears to be forgiving in one case and not in the other. I am using PHP 7 and your first example throws the same Strict standards message.

When developing, [enable E_STRICT](http://www.kreci.net/web-development/how-to-enable-error-reporting-in-php-script/) so that you can catch forgiving constraints.

Comment: yes, I know that. I supposed to that it should be the same, both situation should show the message, but it didnot, I am just curious about those two situation

Comment: I downloaded 5.4 and am curious why Strictness check is done with include/require but not otherwise. I don't have the answer. If I find an answer, I'll update it here. I think your question is very good.